# Spring boot application is not getting installed when 2 jvm are running on Unix server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jboss, db2

I have 2 application both are connected to DB2 using jndi and are installed on same jboss location but on different JVM. both are having different jndi name as well but it's connected to same db and same user.

While starting server if one app is up, we are unable to install 2nd application.

Can this be spring boot DB2 connectivity issue? Or configuration of servers are not proper.

My question may not be properly understandable as I am posting anything for the first time here.

Comment: Are you running two instances of jboss using same configuration? Second instance of jboss will not start due to port conflicts and other issues.

Comment: We have fixed configuration issue and have made sure that ports are not conflicting.

Comment: While deploying new war file we are getting connection pooling error which was mostly cause of driver not found we have provided that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fixed this issue cause,
Issue was we were not mentioning any initialSize in Jndi datasource and it was taking by Default value which is 10.
And at Db side we have restriction that only 30 connection can be established, since we were able to bring 4th appliup which means we were trying to create 10 more connections (30 already created by other 3 application) db was getting locked and it wasn't allowing us to deploy the code.